# How to install macOS on an erased SSD of an old MBP?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, ssd, install

I have a 2010 MacBook Pro which I am trying to reinstall macOS High Sierra. I installed Windows 10 on it previously but encountered many problems while using it. So, I erased the SSD.

Now, I am trying to freshly install macOS High Sierra on it. I have tried internet recovery but I am unable to download the OS and reinstall it as it keeps saying recovery server could not be contacted. I have also tried various methods to fix that, but they have all failed.

I know I can make a bootable USB using another Mac, but I have access only to computers running Windows.

1. I have tried to restore a disk image using the internet recovery option, but it has failed. How can I restore a disk image given my situation?
2. If this is not possible, can I make a bootable USB drive using Windows to install macOS?
3. If either of the above is not possible, how else I can install macOS on my SSD without the help of another Mac?

Pls note that I don't want to use any paid software.